# How to Customize WordPress Post Thumbnails?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

How can I override the default "Natural" size for thumbnails in WordPress? My functions.php and CSS is not working. It makes the image blurry.

[image: Screenshot]

**Functions.php**

```
// Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages.
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size( 450, 250, true );
```

**Style.css:**

```
/*  Featured image thumbnail */
.attachment-post-thumbnail, .size-post-thumbnail, .wp-post-image { 
    width: 450px !important; 
    height: 250px !important; 
}
```

**Page-blog.php (Custom blog page):**

```
       <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" 
    <?php post_class(); ?>>
              <h2 class=""> 
<a class="blog-title" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a> </h2>
                 <div class="entry-content"> <?php 
          if ( has_post_thumbnail ) {                                            
             the_post_thumbnail();
                                     }
                               the_excerpt();   
                                                    ?> 
                                          </div>
                                     </article>
```

In **Google Dev Tools**, the **HTML renders** like this below. Notice that it attaches the default 150 x 150 (**I don't have it hard coded this way**):

```
   <div class="entry-content"> 
    <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/feature_nothavingit-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-post-thumbnail size-post-thumbnail wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/feature_nothavingit-150x150.jpg 150w, http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/feature_nothavingit-45x45.jpg 45w" sizes="(max-width: 150px) 100vw, 150px">
```

Comment: From the docs `When using the_post_thumbnail() or related functions, the ‘post-thumbnail’ image size is used by default, though a different size can be specified instead as needed.`  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: Thank you. I tried code from there but nothing appeared to work. I'll take a second look or ask a friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better practice is to use the url of thumbnail by method [get_the_post_thumbnail_url()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/). You just need to use the next structure and you can make any custom thumbnail. And be sure, that you have an additional image with needed resolution. For correct work on all resolutions the best practice is to use [`<picture></picture>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_source.asp) selector.

```
$thumbnail_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(the_ID(), 'post-thumbnails');

<div class="entry-content"> 
     <img src='<?php echo $thumbnail_url; ?>'>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This led me in the right direction and fixed the issue. It strangely printed out a number on the side of the image though. I was able to debug it with a friend.